# android GridView layout with 2 ImageView as child view

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout

I'd like to create a GridView layout with fixed column size (lets say 80dp). As child element (cell) I'd like to have 2 ImageView:
1. One ImageView that fills up the entire cell - it is a thumbnail image.
2. 2nd ImageView paddedd to bottom right, being a small 12x12 icon that should overlay 1st ImageView.

How to achieve that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this layout. Please note that the code below might have spelling mistakes, or might use drawables that might not exist in your project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/image_and_text_layout" android:paddingBottom="5dip" android:paddingTop="5dip" android:layout_height="80dip" android:layout_width="80dip">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/option_image" android:src="@drawable/background_night_blue_gradient" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/option1_image" android:src="@drawable/icon" android:scaleType="fitXY" android:layout_height="12dip" android:layout_width="12dip" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```